# get beacon notifications when in background iOS Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uialertview, core-location, ibeacon

I have an app that lets two people play a game over bluetooth.  When one player sends out an invitation to play they are turning their phone into a beacon.  When this beacon is turned on the other people with the app (if in range) register they have crossed into the range and a notification pops up.  This works great when the app is open.  However when the app is in the background the notification is received but not shown to the user until they wake the app back up.  How do I make it so that either the notification is shown or a sound is played or both when the app is in the background mode.

Here is the code I use to receive region.state and display notification.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion*)region{
NSLog(@"manager didDetermineState state forRegion");

UILocalNotification *notification  = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

if(state == CLRegionStateInside){
    NSLog(@"region.identifier;%@",region.identifier);

   if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"com.checkers.bluetooth"]) {
        NSLog(@"region.identifier;%@",region.identifier);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
                if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480.0){
                    inviteCheckers.frame = CGRectMake(147,95 *.84,20,20);
                }
                else {
                    inviteCheckers.frame = CGRectMake(147,95,20,20);}
            }
            else if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
                inviteCheckers.frame = CGRectMake(64+294,145,40,40);
            }
        } completion:^ (BOOL completed) {
```

if ([yourName isEqualToString:@"None"]) {
                    notification.alertBody = @"You missed someone inviting you to play Checkers.\nOpen I'M GAME and send out an invite.";
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
                }
                else {
                NSString *nameString1 = yourName;
                NSString *nameString2 = [nameString1 stringByAppendingString:@" wants to play checkers."];
                notification.alertBody = nameString2;
                AlertView= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Play a Game?"
                                                      message:notification.alertBody

```
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"CANCEL", nil];
                            [self.AlertView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [AlertView show];}    }     ];

        identifierString = region.identifier;

         messageString2 = @"checkers";
        recieve.hidden = NO;
     }
```

//this is new code I have added

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{


if ([backgroundstring isEqualToString:@"fire"]) {
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    notification.alertBody = @"Someone wants to play a game.";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}

}
```

It seems that this used to work but now it doesn't.
I have location updates in background mode in plist.
I get permissions
Now when the app is in the background an there is an invite but no name is recorded a notification appears but in foreground gets alert with the person's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code references `UILocalNotification` but does not send one.  It instead presents a `UIView` and an alert dialog, actions which will only be visible when the app is in the foreground.

In order to alert the user if the app is not in the foreground, the only tool iOS gives you is a `UILocalNotification`.  You must present this to the user if the app is in the background.  If the user taps on it, it will bring the app to the foreground.

Comment: I have added a backgroundstring which changes from @"no fire"; to @"fire"; when the alert notification comes in and that works.  And then I tried to send a local notification when the backgroundstring is @"fire";  (see code above) but nothing happens.  I'm sure i'm missing something but don't know what.

Comment: Figured it out thanks for the hint. I'll post my code to reflect what I did.